# Fish selection question - combination and permutation, elementary set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Case:** Suppose there are two 100-fish tanks, and one fish is to be chosen from each tank.

Question 1: Assuming that the **order in which the fish are chosen is irrelevant** (That is, all that matters is which two fish are chosen, not which is chosen first), there are $C_{200}^2=19,900$ ways to make the selection.

Question 2: If **the order is important**, there are  $P_{200}^2=39,800$ ways to make the selection.

Please let me know if my answers are correct.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first answer is wrong, because you have specified that each fish comes from a different tank.  So, there are $(100)^2$ possibilities.  Your answer would be correct if you were allowed to choose both fish from the same tank.

Regardless of whether the fish are or are not allowed to come from the same tank, whatever the appropriate answer is, the appropriate answer to part $2$ will be $2$ times the previous answer.  That is because there are two ways of ordering the fish.

Comment: thank you so much, I've made a terrible mistake in understanding the concept and question context.